# Draw a linewith angle+distance from lng+lon

Tags: math, geometry, geolocation, geo

I want to draw line (find the endpoint of the line) from a Geopoint (Lan/Lon) and an angle + distance.

I'm calculating the target coordinates by using trigonometric caluclations:
lon2=lon1+(sin(course*180/PI)*distance)
lat2=lat1+(cos(course*180/PI)*distance)
but this approach i returning the wrong coordinates.